# Making a variable number of parallel HTTP requests with Gatling?

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I am trying to model a server-to-server REST API interaction in Gatling 2.2.0. There are several interactions of the type "request a list and then request all items on the list at in parallel", but I can't seem to model this in Gatling. Code so far:

```
def groupBy(dimensions: Seq[String], metric: String) = {
  http("group by")
    .post(endpoint)
    .body(...).asJSON
    .check(
      ...
      .saveAs("events")
    )
}

scenario("Dashboard scenario")
  .exec(groupBy(dimensions, metric)
    .resources(
      // a http() for each item in session("events"), plz 
    )
  )
```

I have gotten as far as figuring out that parallel requests are performed by .resources(), but I don't understand how to generate a list of requests to feed it. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Below approach is working for me. Seq of HttpRequestBuilder will be executed concurrently:

```
val numberOfParallelReq = 1000

val scn = scenario("Some scenario")
  .exec(
    http("first request")
      .post(url)
      .resources(parallelRequests: _*)
      .body(StringBody(firstReqBody))
      .check(status.is(200))
  )

def parallelRequests: Seq[HttpRequestBuilder] =
  (0 until numberOfParallelReq).map(i => generatePageRequest(i))

def generatePageRequest(id: Int): HttpRequestBuilder = {

  val body = "Your request body here...."

  http("page")
    .post(url)
    .body(StringBody(body))
    .check(status.is(200))
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Is it possible to get access to `session("events")` inside `parallelRequests` ?

Comment: is there any way we can pass feeder data into these request?

Comment: What feeder data do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure of your query but seems like you need to send parallel request which can be done by  
`setUp(scenorio.inject(atOnceUsers(NO_OF_USERS)));`

Refer this http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/simulation_setup.html

Comment: This will not perform requests depending on data as retrieved from the API, but simply run an unrelated, fix-rate set of queries. As far as I understand, there is no way to parametrize scenarios from other scenarios.